# Python : error while plotting 3d graph from 3 arrays

Tags: python, 3d, mplot3d

I have three equal-length arrays named ra, ma and op with mostly numbers **and few instances when they have 'nan' or 'None' in place of a number**.
Eg:

```
ra = [0, 1, 2, nan, 8 , 3, 8, 5]
ma = [3, nan, 5, 8, 9, 6, 4, 10]
op = [7, None, 7, 9, 3, 6, None, 7]
```

I want to make a 3d plot of the numbers in them. My code is :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(ra,ma,op)

plt.show()
```

Everything is fine till I type plt.show() - then it gives me a long list of error which ends like:

```
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'".
```

**May be:**
It is because of the nan values, but i do not know how to remove them :-/ if i want to remove the nan value from ra (which is the 4th value of list), i will also have to remove the respective 4th values from ma and op. And I can not figure out how to do that or if at all we need to do that.

Can someone please point out where i am going wrong??

Comment: The error is pretty clear; it is *not* complaining about `nan`s but about `None`s.

Comment: is it possible to remove the None values from the list 'op' and also remove the corresponding values from 'ra' and 'ma'?

I mean, it should be possible, but i do not know how to put a for loop to consider all these three arrays..

Comment: Using `itertools.compress` is pretty easy: `op, ma, ra = zip(*compress(zip(op, ma, ra), op))` (this assumes `op` doesn't contain zeros. Otherwise replace `op` with `(x is not None for x in op)`. Using an explicit loop you can do `for a, b, c in zip(ra, ma, op)` check if `c is not None` in that case insert `a`, `b` and `c` into some new lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get rid of columns with`None`in them like this (in either Python 2.7 or 3+):

```
from __future__ import print_function
try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:
    izip = zip

ra = [0, 1, 2, float('nan'), 8 , 3, 8, 5]
ma = [3, float('nan'), 5, 8, 9, 6, 4, 10]
op = [7, None, 7, 9, 3, 6, None, 7]

ra, ma, op = izip(*(col for col in izip(ra, ma, op) if None not in col))

print('ra =', ra)
print('ma =', ma)
print('op =', op)
```

Output:

```
ra = (0, 2, nan, 8, 3, 5)
ma = (3, 5, 8, 9, 6, 10)
op = (7, 7, 9, 3, 6, 7)
```

As @Bakuriu mentioned in a comment, it might be a better to use the`compress()`function which is in the built-in`itertools`module and is therefore likely to be faster. It also eliminates the relatively slow linear search through each column of values in the above.

```
from itertools import compress
ra, ma, op =  izip(*compress(izip(ra, ma, op), (x is not None for x in op)))
```